# "Problem9": Packing a list

Tags: list, f#, pattern-matching, matching, packing

I'm learning f# with no prior functional programming background - starting to make progress but been stuck on this one. Could anybody please help me understand the solution to Problem 9 of the 99 f# problems - they can be found here:[http://fssnip.net/an][1]

Basically I don't understand how the pattern matching works in the provided solution. For a start what is xss? cheers for any help!

Problem 9 : Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.
If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed  in separate sublists.

Example:

pack ['a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'c'; 'a'; 'a'; 'd'; 'e'; 'e'; 'e'; 'e']

val it : char list list =
[['a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a']; ['b']; ['c'; 'c']; ['a'; 'a']; ['d']; ['e'; 'e'; 'e'; 'e']]

Sample Solution;

```
let pack xs = 
    let collect x = function
        | (y::xs)::xss when x = y -> (x::y::xs)::xss
        | xss -> [x]::xss
    List.foldBack collect xs []
```

Comment: this is a good resource:
[link] http://diditwith.net/2008/03/03/WhyILoveFListsTheBasics.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, it is first important to understand how lists are represented in F#. An F# list is either:

- an empty list written as `[]` or
- a value (head) followed by another list (tail) written as `head::tail`

So if you write, for example, `[ 1; 2; 3 ]` you are actually constructing a list containing 1, followed by a list containing 2, (etc.) followed by an empty list. The expression is compiled to:

```
1::(2::(3::[]))
```

And you can omit the brackets and write just `1::2::3::[]`.

Pattern matching uses exactly the same syntax, but in the opposite direction. Instead of constructing lists, you are *decomposing* them. So when you have a pattern `x::xs` it means that you want to take the first element and assign it to a variable `x` and the remaining list should be assinged to a variable `xs`.

The pattern `(x::xs)::xss` is a bit more tricky, because it works on *lists of lists*. This means that the head of the list you match on is also a list. You could rewrite the code to the following simpler version:

```
let pack xs = 
    let collect x = function
        | head::xss ->    // Decompose into first element (head) and the rest (tail)
          match head with
          | y::xs when x = y -> (x::y::xs)::xss
          | _ -> [x]::xss
        | xss -> [x]::xss
    List.foldBack collect xs []
```

Now you have some duplication in the code, but you can see that `collect` takes `x` and another parameter, matches that another parameter against `head::xss` (to get the head/tail) and then also decomposes the `head`.

Answer (score 1):

`(y::xs)::xss` matches a (non-empty) list of lists, `y` and `xs` being the head and tail of the first sublist and `xss` being the tail of the outer list. `xss`, in the second case, matches the entire list (empty or not).

[`foldBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353846.aspx) (`('T -> 'State -> 'State) -> 'T list -> 'State -> 'State`) threads an accumulator argument through the list, going from back to front.

`collect` is the "accumulating" function, which basically reads: if the state (initially an empty list) contains at least one sublist, which is also non-empty, and the current element (`x`) matches the head of the sublist (`y`), prepend `x` to the sublist, otherwise prepend a new sublist to the state (`xss`) consisting solely of `x`. Each sublist is a group of equal, adjacent elements.

Comment: cheers for your answer - it finally clicked! The pattern matching is on the item in the xs list (with foldBack its the last item first) and the pattern matching is on the seed [] in the example above. Obvious now.... not so obvious before - thanks again!